# How do I install jenkins in RHEL 7.3 VM?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install Jenkins in RHEL  7.3 VM, but I only get this:

```
[root@btpvm3716 ~]# wget http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war
--2016-03-11 05:08:43--  http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war
Resolving mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)|52.202.51.185|:80.           .. failed: Connection timed out.``
Retrying.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It just looks like you are not able to connect to the internet. Maybe you've forgetten to configure a needed proxy?

Comment: oh.. k thank you .. let me check